# How to set html5 video height fixed?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am trying to set a html5 video as full page background, so what I want to achieve is 100% width and height which I got it that code:

```
.container{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#video{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
video{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

But as you narrow the page the video height will gets shorter..
See: http://jsfiddle.net/qe7hR/9/

However I want to do something like that: http://www.bkwld.com/
As you narrow the page video height is still fixed to page height..

Whatever I tried didn't work..Do I need to use a jquery/js for this?
How do I achieve that?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
video{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

By

```
video{
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

to your CSS

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/qe7hR/14/)**

Comment: Man! that's what I am looking for..I had tried min-height but didnt't work because I didn't set min-width too.. Thanx!